# How do I pass an arbitrary argument to an Azure WebJob SDK method?

Tags: f#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure WebJob function using the Trigger schedule:

```
let resetTablesWebJob([<TimerTrigger "*/10 * * * * *">] timer:TimerInfo) =
    // do stuff
    ()
```

However I want to pass some contextual information as well into the webjob e.g.

```
let resetTablesWebJob([<TimerTrigger "*/10 * * * * *">] timer:TimerInfo, myData:Foo) =
    // do stuff with myData, too.
    ()
```

I've seen some posts on SO and elsewhere that go through the whole hassle of doing this with DI and AutoFac etc. etc. - is there a slightly more lightweight way of doing this, where I can simple pass in to the `JobConfig` at initialisation time some object or value which will later on be picked up by the binding engine during webjob invocations?

Comment: you can use static objects if it is independent from context

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I'm looking for a way to pass it in as an argument.

Comment: You can't. You have to use DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.  The timer is a trigger, and triggers invoke your function. There's no opportunity to pass in an argument along with the trigger. The only allowed arguments are the trigger argument and bindings that might be derived from the trigger.

Instead, you can:

1. Reference a static variable.
2. Use an IJobActivator and pass to create an instance of the class and then pass in the arg via an instance property. This is the building block for DI, but just using IJobActivator directly can be more lightweight than a full DI.
3. Use a binding. For example, put your argument in a blob (or table, or file, or redis, or anything else you bind to) and then bind to it. Ie, in `[<Blob('container/blob.txt')>] data :string`

Comment: So I suppose I could create a custom binding and attach that to the web jobs host with my metadata?

Comment: I listed them in order of simplicity. If you can use a static, that's the easiest. (and given that you have a timer trigger, a static should work).  I'd avoid a custom binding for this - that's overkill.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same. Statics aren't really something I want to use though - they normally require (or at least imply the use of) mutable variables and I want to illustrate something that fits in more nicely with FP best practices.